# stored procedure for inserting data into multiple tables in database using servlet

Tags: oracle, jsp, stored-procedures

How can I write a stored procedure for inserting multiple rows in an html table on a jsp page to an oracle database. 
I have written a procedure in the following way, but it isn't working:

```
create or replace procedure insert_service_detail(
    p_challandetailid in cm_challan_details.challandetailsid%type, 
    p_challanid in cm_challan_details.challanid%type,
    p_serviceid in cm_challan_details.serviceid%type,
    p_year in cm_challan_details.year%type,
    p_month in cm_challan_details.month%TYPE, 
    p_fee in cm_challan_details.fee%type, 
    p_cess in cm_challan_details.cess%type, 
    p_penalty in cm_challan_details.penalty%type, 
    p_total in cm_challan_details.total%type) as 
begin
    insert into CM_CHALLAN_DETAILS(challanid, serviceid, year, month, fee, cess, penalty, total) 
    values(p_challandetailid, p_challanid, p_serviceid, p_year, p_month, p_fee, p_cess, p_penalty, p_total); 
end insert_service_detail;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of arguments do not match in the INSERT query.. Please check.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You are right.. I didnt notice it. Actually the parameters which i am passing in insert query are coming from jsp page. And the other 3 values, i am not passing in jsp.. Should i remove those 3 parameters...?

Comment: Make those parameters null if you do not want to insert in those 3 fields of table. But you can also remove them from procedure and query inside it.

Comment: first parameter is primary key so it will be auto generated. the other 2 values can be declared null.

Comment: @anusha ok that is in your hands what you do. Please accept the answer if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my question,

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_DETAILS
(
p_challanid in table1.CHALLANID%type,
p_ulbid in table1.ulbid%type,
p_challanno in table1.CHALLANNO%type,
p_challanDate in table1.CHALLANDATE%type,
p_createdby in table1.CREATEDBY%type,
p_createdon in table1.CREATEDON%type,
p_finyearid in table1.FINYEARID%type,
p_challanstatus in table1.CHALLANSTATUS%TYPE,
p_name in table2.APPLICANTNAME%type,
p_addr in table2.APPLICANTADDRESS%type,
p_email in table2.APPLICANTEMAIL%type,
p_mobile in table2.MOBILENO%type,
p_contact in table2.CONTACTNO%type,
p_challandetailid in table3.challandetailid%type,
p_details_challanid in table3.CHALLANID%type,
p_serviceid in table3.serviceid%type,
p_year in table3.year%type,
p_month in table3.month%TYPE,
p_fee in table3.fee%type,
p_cess in table3.cess%type,
p_penalty in table3.penalty%type,
p_total in table3.total%type
)
AS 
BEGIN
insert into table1(challanid, ulbid, challanno, CHALLANDATE, createdby, createdon, finyearid, CHALLANSTATUS) VALUESVALUES( 2, 1002, 'chln02', p_challandate, 'asdasd', to_date('02/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 10002, 'Y');
insert into table2(challinid, APPLICANTNAME, APPLICANTADDRESS, APPLICANTEMAIL, MOBILENO, CONTACTNO) values( 2, 2, 'abcd', p_addr, p_email, p_mobile, p_contact);
insert into table3( challandetailid, challanid, serviceid, year, month, fee, cess, penalty, total) values( 2, 102, 2, p_year, p_month, 10.25, 0.25, 0.1, 10.61); 
commit;
END INSERT_CHALLAN_DETAILS;
```

I got this values inserted into database and also inserted into 3 tables....